# Why can't I use `sum` for a list created by splitting the user input?

Tags: python, list, function, sum

I am doing my homework and it requirers me to use a sum () and len () functions to find the mean of an input number list, when I tried to use sum () to get the sum of the list, I got an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. Following is my code:

```
numlist = input("Enter a list of number separated by commas: ")

numlist = numlist.split(",")

s = sum(numlist)
l = len(numlist)
m = float(s/l)
print("mean:",m)
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that when you read from the input, you have a list of strings. You could do something like that as your second line:

```
numlist = [float(x) for x in numlist]
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you have a list of strings. You need to convert them to integers before you compute the sum. For example:

```
numlist = numlist.split(",")
numlist = map(int, numlist)
s = sum(numlist)
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You are adding up strings, not numbers, which is what your error message is saying.

Convert every string into its respective integer:

```
numlist = map(int, numlist)
```

And then take the average (note that I use `float()` differently than you do):

```
arithmetic_mean = float(sum(numlist)) / len(numlist)
```

You want to use `float()` before dividing, as `float(1/2) = float(0) = 0.0`, which isn't what you want.

An alternative would be to just make them all `float` in the first place:

```
numlist = map(float, numlist)
```

Comment: Unless the OP is in Py3, in which case true division is the default.

Comment: Hmm, that could also be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Split returns you an array of strings, so you need to convert these to integers before using the sum function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [float(x) for x in distance])
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string input to a list of float values. Here is the updated code.

```
numlist = list(map(int,input("Enter a list of number separated by commas: ").split(',')))
l = len(numlist)
s = sum(numlist)
print("mean :",s/l)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7

```
numlist = map(int,raw_input().split(","))
s = sum(numlist)
l = len(numlist)
m = float(s/l)
print("mean:"+ str(m))
```